# disable web middleware for specific routes in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, middleware, laravel-5

I want to guest users have access to home page but in built in authentication process laravel redirects to login page. how can i give guest users access to home page?

my routes.php:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'web'], function () {
Route::auth();

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');

Route::get('/insert', 'HomeController@insertform');
Route::get('/job/{id}', 'JobsController@show');

Route::get('/city/{city}', 'JobsController@city');

Route::post('/insert', 'HomeController@insert');
Route::get('/cityinsert', 'HomeController@cityinsert');
Route::post('/cityinsert', 'HomeController@cityinsertpost');

});
```

and authenticate.php

```
class Authenticate
{
 /**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @param  string|null  $guard
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->guest()) {
        if ($request->ajax()) {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
        } else {
            return redirect()->guest('login');
        }
    }

    return $next($request);
}
}
```

and this is my kernel.php

```
class Kernel extends HttpKernel
{
/**
 * The application's global HTTP middleware stack.
 *
 * These middleware are run during every request to your application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middleware = [
    \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\CheckForMaintenanceMode::class,
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware groups.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $middlewareGroups = [
    'web' => [
        \App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
        \Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
        \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
        \Illuminate\View\Middleware\ShareErrorsFromSession::class,
        \App\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    ],

    'api' => [
        'throttle:60,1',
    ],
];

/**
 * The application's route middleware.
 *
 * These middleware may be assigned to groups or used individually.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'auth' => \App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate::class,
    'auth.basic' => \Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth::class,
    'guest' => \App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated::class,
    'throttle' => \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests::class,
];
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Remove the middleware from HomeController construct:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->middleware('auth');
    }
}
```

Comment: This is GREAT! now i get a message blocking my page that reads "You are logged in! " please help im going to pull my hair out.

Answer (score 48):

I prefer to exclude middleware via routes. You can do it in two ways:

1. Single action:

```php
Route::post('login', 'LoginController@login')->withoutMiddleware(['auth']);
```

2. Group mode:

```php
Route::group([
    'prefix' => 'forgot-password',
    'excluded_middleware' => ['auth'],
], function () {
    Route::post('send-email', 'ForgotPasswordController@sendEmail');
    Route::post('save-new-password', 'ForgotPasswordController@saveNewPassword');
});
```

Tested on Laravel 7.7

Comment: +1 Excluding middleware in route is great because even if a middleware is added in constructor, it still won't let that register thus saves headache of tempering controller

Comment: What a wonderful answer!!  Thank you very much friend. I tested it here and it is possible to exclude middlewares and include them at the same time.

Comment: As a side note, `withoutMiddleware()` method only available for Laravel 7.x and above. [Read this reference API](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_withoutMiddleware)

Comment: That's not really a side note.  The question is specifically "How to do this in Laravel 5.2".  This answer does not work for the version in question.

Answer (score 33):

Add an exception in the middleware declaration in the construct

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index');
```

for the above route to be exempted from authentication you should pass the function name to the middleware like below

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => 'index']);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I can add to  Sidharth answer, that you can use several methods exeption, by including them in array:

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index', 'show']]);
    }
}
```

Laravel 5.5 tested.

Answer (score 3):

You can also separate between `middleware` and `except`. Try this one :

```
/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest')->except([
        'submitLogout',
        'showUserDetail'
    ]);
}
```

Tested on Laravel 5.4

Answer (score 2):

**Add except URL to VerifyCsrfToken**

```
app/http/middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php
```

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as Middleware;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends Middleware
{
    /**
     * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $except = [
        'stripe/*',
        'http://example.com/foo/bar',
        'http://example.com/foo/*',
    ];
}
```

Source: [Laravel Documentation CSRF exclude URL](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-excluding-uris)

*Tested on Lavarel 7.0 as well

Answer (score 0):

Recently I need that functionality in an old Laravel project.

God bless Laravel for macroable feature :)

AppServiceProvider.php

```
public function boot()
    {
        Route::macro('withoutMiddleware', function ($excludedMiddlewares) {
            $this->action['middleware'] = array_filter(
                $this->action['middleware'],
                function ($middleware) use ($excludedMiddlewares) {
                    return !in_array($middleware, $excludedMiddlewares);
                });

            return $this;
        });
    }
```

Then you can use it like this:

```
Route::get('something')->withoutMiddleware(['auth']);
```